# Hasura query that works similar to a SQL Left join

Tags: sql-server, graphql, left-join, hasura

Assume the following SQL Server table structure

```
dbo.users
(
    id int not null,
    favoriteBook int null --fk
)

dbo.books
(
    id int not null,
    title nvarchar(max)
)
```

Assuming a user exists that has not entered in  their favorite book I'd like to use Hasura's GraphQL engine to search for all users and return the title of their favorite book if one exists, or null if it doesn't.

I'd expect something like this to work:

```
query Users{
  users {
    id
    FavoriteBook {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

However when using this query the engine returns the following error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "internal": {
          "tag": "unsuccessful_return_code",
          "contents": [
            "odbc_SQLExecDirectW",
            -1,
            "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 4.[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 4."
          ]
        },
        "path": "$",
        "code": "unexpected"
      },
      "message": "sql server exception"
    }
  ]
}
```

The SQL generated by Hasura looks something like this:

```
select
  isnull (
  (
    select
      [t_Users1].[id] as [id]
      ,json_query ( [or_books1].[json] ) as [FavoriteBook]
    from  [dbo].[users] as [t_Users1]
      outer apply
    (
      select
        isnull ((
                  select
                    [t_Books1].[id] as [id]
                  from  [dbo].[books] as [t_Books1]
                  where
                    (([t_Books1].[id]) = ([t_Users1].[favoriteBook]))
                  for json path, include_null_values, without_array_wrapper
                )
                ,'null'
               )
    ) as [or_Booksr1]([json])
    order by
      (
        select  null
      ) /* ORDER BY is required for OFFSET */ offset 0 rows fetch next 1000 rows only
    for json path, include_null_values
  )
  ,'[]'
         )
;
```

Ideally the output would look something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 254,
        "favoriteBook": {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "book about foo"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 892,
        "favoriteBook": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty weird that should happen. It's caused by a one-parameter `JSON_QUERY` call bugging out on input which is supposed to already be JSON. But the JSON is being generated by `for json path` so not sure how that could happen. Can you try executing it yourself, but change that line to just `,[or_books1].[json] as [FavoriteBook]` and post the output. That will cause string escaping, but I'd like to see what it looks like. Perhaps there's an invalid character somewhere, or some other `FOR JSON` bug

Comment: Must say, this query is entertaining: `ORDER BY ... OFFSET 0 ROWS` is unnecessary, could have just used `TOP (1000)`. And `ISNULL(... 'null')` is not necessary if using `include_null_values`, in fact I think it will cause spurious `"null"` rather than `null` values

Comment: Well I was able to run it without the `json_query ` function and it runs, the output is something much more along the lines of what I'm expecting. However you are correct the FavoriteBook object when missing the relation is `"null"` rather than `null` the object it's self is also quoted though `"{""id": 1,"title": "book about foo"}"` rathar than `{""id": 1,"title": "book about foo"}`. At this point though the goal would be to get this query to generate correctly via Hasura though.

Comment: That's because you are not using `JSON_QUERY` so it thinks it's just a string and puts extra `"` in. Are you sure there is a double `""` there and not `\"`, can you paste in your **exact** result

Comment: A ticket was opened [here](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/8319) for the issue.